# laravel blade syntax in dynamic javascript form creation

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-blade

I want to make dynamic form with javascript that generated after clicking a button and append it to parent element. but in that form i want to use laravel blade syntax which is

```
{!! Form::open(['url' =>'#somelink','method' => 'PUT','id' => 'form1'])!!}
<div> ..... </div> 
{{!! Form::close !!}
```

can i use that syntax in javascript create element? if i can't do that how can i make form that have similar function like code above which created dynamicly with javascript.

Comment: How about using `jQuery.clone()` ?

Comment: @Rayon can i generate new form with put method everytime i click a button? i think put method only exist in laravel blade syntax but with pure html i dont know how it looks like. i also want every input element inside that form have different id value from form element which have been created before. does jquery.clone can generate new element with unique id value?

Comment: IMO, You do not need to manipulate anything over server side, this can be acieved using `DOM-manipulations` using `JavaScript/jQuery`.... Read about [__`jQuery.clone()`__](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)